# Can't add columns to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add some columns to a pandas dataframe. Before adding them the df look like this:

```
time    open    high    low close   tick_volume spread  real_volume
0   2018-01-02 00:00:00 1.16987 1.17074 1.16853 1.17006 307 136 0
```

I am now trying to add columns by doing it like this:

```
import utils
import pandas as pd 
    
tradeable_pairs = ["CADCHF", "CADJPY", "CHFJPY", "EURCAD", "EURCHF", "EURGBP", "EURJPY", "EURNZD", 
    "EURUSD", "GBPCAD", "GBPCHF", "GBPJPY", "GBPNZD", "GBPNZD", "GBPUSD", "NZDCAD", "NZDCHF",
    "NZDJPY", "NZDUSD", "USDCAD", "USDCHF", "USDJPY"]

for pair in tradeable_pairs:
    df = pd.read_pickle(utils.get_his_data_filename(pair, "H1"))
    df['EMA_LONG'] = df.close.ewm(span=26, min_periods=26).mean()
    df['EMA_SHORT'] = df.close.ewm(span=12, min_periods=12).mean()
    df['MACD'] = df.EMA_SHORT - df.EMA_LONG
    df['SIGNAL'] = df.MACD.ewm(span=9).mean()
    df['HIST'] = df.MACD - df.SIGNAL
    df.head()
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

The df's I want to change are named like "EURUSD_H1.pkl" and so on. Thats why I am using "utils.get_his_data_filename(pair, "H1")". The function "get_his_data_filename" is the just returning the path to the different df's like this:

```
def get_his_data_filename(pair, granularity):
    return f"his_data/{pair}_{granularity}.pkl"
```

After doing this I want to check what the df's looks like and I picked some random tradeable_pairs by doing this:

```
df2 = pd.read_pickle(utils.get_his_data_filename("EURCHF", "H1"))
df2.head(50)
```

But the df output remains the same as before. So no columns were added.

```
time    open    high    low close   tick_volume spread  real_volume
0   2018-01-02 00:00:00 1.16987 1.17074 1.16853 1.17006 307 136 0
```

Am I blind or what is the problem here?
Thank you already!

Comment: Are you saving back to disk the enriched data frames?

Comment: How would I do that? I thought open/read the df and change it would be enough.

Comment: Lookup `.to_pickle()` ... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle

Comment: Well it worked. Thank you very much!